# Bootstrap - Inline form button not aligning vertically to other inputs

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]
I can't seem to get this friggen button to line up with the form controls. I have tried using the following strategies with no success:

```
<div class="input-group">
 <input type="text" class="form-control">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
   <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
  </span>
</div>  


<div class="input-append">
 <input name="search" id="search"/>
  <button class="btn">button</button>
</div>
```

I have seen that class `form-horizontal`is also a possibility but still does not work for me. I end up with:
[image]

Here is my HTML

```
<form action="/Account/logoff" class="form-inline" method="post" role="form" novalidate="novalidate">                <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="Username">Username</label>
                <input class="form-control form-text" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Username field is required." id="Username" name="Username" placeholder="Username" type="text" value="">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="Password">Password</label>
                <input class="form- control form-text" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Password field is required." id="Password" name="Password" placeholder="Password" type="password">
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Login</button>
</form>
```

**Update**
It seems that my controls are somehow bleeding through the form element.
[image]

**Update 2**- For Christina

```
<header role="banner" class="navbar navbar-inverse">
<div class="navbar-header">
    <button id="menu-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" type="button" class="navbar-toggle">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand"> <img alt="logo" src="images/logo.png"> </a>
</div>

<!--User is logged on, output user controls-->
    <div class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
<form action="/Account/logoff" class="form-inline" method="post" role="form" novalidate="novalidate">                <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="Username">Username</label>
                <input class="form-control form-text" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Username field is required." id="Username" name="Username" placeholder="Username" type="text" value="">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="Password">Password</label>
                <input class="form- control form-text" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Password field is required." id="Password" name="Password" placeholder="Password" type="password">
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Login</button>
</form>        </div>


</header>
```

Comment: `input-append` is bootstrap 2 is this what you want?

Comment: No, I'm using bootstrap 3. Maybe that's why that did not work for me..

Comment: Your navbar classes are wrong. Use navbar-right not pull-right also provide the full navbar html

Comment: Why don't you use this navbar to start you off http://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron/

Comment: The navbar-form not form-inline

Comment: @Adrian you can do like this [example](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-forms) in Bootstrap docs

Comment: I'm actually working off a template. I'm trying to modify this navbar that came with it. I didn't think the problem would be in the nav but that does make sense now that you mention it.

Comment: People who make templates are not necessarily that good with bootstrap I've seen some serious problems everywhere I look. All classes that have to do with forms don't work well in the navbar, you must use the classes they provide or make a new component, also you don't pull-right you navbar-right and navbar-left.

Comment: Christina, I just took a look at your jumbotron example. I'm going to try and redo their navbar with those same classes and see what happens.

Comment: Look at the classes .. navbar-text (text), navbar-right (flush right), navbar-left, navbar-form, things that go inside a navbar are navbar specific.

Comment: I found the problem. I'm sure it has to do with my custom .form-text class. I copy pasted the bootstrap navbar and added my text classes to the inputs and now everything is mis-aligned

Answer (score 0):

In this case the lesson learned was: *Don't trust css is correct just because it's offered under a professional bootstrap theme.*

I can't necessarily say this is the answer but I decided to use the jumbotron example provided by bootstrap to start over on my own navbar.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Email" class="form-control input-sm form-text">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control input-sm form-text">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Sign in</button>
        </form>
    </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
</div>
```

With my little touch of css

```
.navbar-inverse input.form-text{
 background-color:#0f1217;
 border: 1px solid #0f1217;
 border-radius: 4px;
 color: #fff;
 transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
```

}